# Automate sql server profiler to record data then save data to a table continuously

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to automate sql server profiler to record data then save data to a table continuously?

The reason, I am supporting a fragile SQL Server application and there is no auditing. I receive a lot of support calls regarding the deletion of records. I want a quick way to be able to view who has changed what data.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your profiler to save the trace directly to table as described here: [How To Save a SQL Server Trace Data to a Table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3507/how-to-save-a-sql-server-trace-data-to-a-table/)

But it's not a good idea for 2 reasons: first, profiler itself will be loading up your server, second, writing to table is the most costly option and you can even loose some events.

Maybe if you are on Enterprise edition you can use [SQL Server database audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/create-a-server-audit-and-database-audit-specification)
that is more light weight

And [here](https://mohammaddarab.com/create-database-audit-for-insert-update-delete-in-sql-server/) you can find a complete example of setting up database audit that audits the DELETE events

Answer (score 0):

Here are few articles for your reference.

Save trace results to a database table

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/save-trace-results-to-a-table-sql-server-profiler

Save Trace Results to a Table

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191276(v=sql.110).aspx

9 Steps to an Automated Trace

http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/9-steps-automated-trace

alternatively, you may try this automated solution ( https://www.lepide.com/lepideauditor/sql-server-auditing.html ) to accomplish this task.